# Trying to construct a Row Widget by calling a function which returns a list of children but this doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a Row Widget which I want to contain a some boxes which each contain a letter and some specific background colors for a game I'm making. I have created a function which returns a list of the Box class instances where each instance has two key attributes initialized for shaping each box but when I add this function to the Row widget children attribute it gives me the following error.

```
Expected a value of type 'List Widget', but got one of type 'List dynamic'
```

When I double check what the function creates it's a list of Box instances but I can't figure out why the Row widget doesn't work with the function

Function that's failing

```
children: wordConstructor("BEARD", "WEIRD")
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  final String letter;
  final String letterState;
  const Box(this.letter, this.letterState);

  setSquareColor(letterState) {
    if (letterState == 'h') {
      return Colors.red.shade700;
    } else {
      return Colors.blue.shade700;
    }
  }

  setCircleColor(letterState) {
    if (letterState == 'h') {
      return Colors.red.shade700;
    }
    if (letterState == 'w') {
      return Colors.yellow.shade800;
    } else {
      return Colors.blue.shade700;
    }
  }

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Container(
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          child: Text(
            widget.letter,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: widget.setCircleColor(widget.letterState),
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ),
      color: widget.setSquareColor(widget.letterState),
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    );
  }
}

wordComparer(wordProvided, wordRequired) {
  List w1 = wordProvided.split('');
  List w2 = wordRequired.split('');
  List result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < w1.length; i++) {
    if (w1[i] == w2[i]) {
      result.add("h");
    } else if (w2.contains(w1[i])) {
      result.add("w");
    } else {
      result.add("c");
    }
  }
  return result;
}

wordConstructor(wordProvided, wordRequired) {
  List l1 = wordProvided.split('');
  List l2 = wordComparer(wordProvided, wordRequired);
  List result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
    result.add(Box(l1[i], l2[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade700,
          title: const Text('Lingo'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          //children: [Box('A', 'h'), Box('B', 'w'), Box('C', 'c')],
          children: wordConstructor("BEARD", "WEIRD"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `List` by itself is shorthand for `List<dynamic>`.  It's better to either be completely explicit (`List<Widget>`) or to let Dart infer the type (`var w1 = wordProvided.split('');`.  Also you should declare return types and parameter types for your functions; otherwise they will be assumed to be `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For default your list var is dynamic, you should try declaring as a list of type widget

```
List<Widget> result = []
```

And add return type to your function

```
List<Widget> wordConstructor(wordProvided, wordRequired) {
```

Comment: Yes! it works thanks a lot :)